# Assigning a value of a field in the main window from IFRAME

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

In an *IFRAME* there's a value declared by `var blipp = 7;`. In the main window, I there's a field called `new_blopp`. I'd be delighted to get *blipp* into *blopp*. According to [this MSDN discussion](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/is/crmdevelopment/thread/bfa0c9c3-16ed-4ed9-a30d-ff2a850b56db), it can be done by one of the following methods.

1. `parent.window.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_blopp").setValue(blipp)`
2. `_mainWindow.parent.parent.document.all["new_blopp"].innerText = blipp`

I'm not entirely sure why he's also suggesting to type in the following.

```
_mainWindow.parent.parent.document.all["new_blopp"].value = ""
```

In any case, neither of them seem to be working. The first gives me *permission denied* and the second *'_mainWindow' is not defined*. Of course, I have unchecked the cross frame scripting. According to F12, there's a field called *data* in *parent.window.Xrm.Page* but it's *null*. When I hit debugger, I can see that *parent* is accessible but not *parent.window* - *permission denied* is what I get there.

How can I convey the wisdom of *blipp* to *blopp*?

It's even more frustrating because [this post](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/is/crmdevelopment/thread/bfa0c9c3-16ed-4ed9-a30d-ff2a850b56db) and [this one](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/3e23486c-358a-4e80-b3e7-e13c77475ce4#4a172efc-35e1-44b1-b686-b21792b17eb2) suggest my code **should** work. does it have to do with the fact that I'm running on-line version?

Comment: is the iframe within the same domain of the parent ?

Comment: @lostsource The *IFRAME* is declaren **within** the CRM, yes. But it points to a resource **outside** it. I can see how that **might** be an issue. How do I circumference it? Or rather, **can** I circumference it?

Comment: you cannot really pass data between iframe/window from different domains http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy as it would be a security risk

Comment: @lostsource Cow poo, then... How about **relaxation** of the limitations? I'm referring especially to *cross-document messaging*...

Answer (score 0):

If both `iframe` and `parent` are in the same domain. (pure `javascript`)

To get `blipp (in iframe)` into `blopp (in parent)`

```
var blopp = document.getElementById("ifameId").contentWindow.blipp;
```

To get `blopp (in parent)` into `blipp (in iframe)`

```
var blipp = self.parent.window.blopp;
```

Comment: Both are in the same domain **but** the source of the *IFRAME* is outside. Also, touching DOM is not supported in CRM so I'd sleep sounder if I could find a supported approach to do what I need.

Comment: This is pure js, works in a normal scenario where iFrame is in the same domain as the parent. Did you try this at all?

Comment: Nope. I'm constrained by the CRM and its SDK. Can't touch DOM object. I know, I know - MS Dynamics CRM is a PIA. I'm only allowed to use the SDK defined methods if the solution is to be supported. Not exactly thrilled about it...

Comment: Okay then, Do you want me to delete this?

Comment: Naa, let it be. It's still a good advice. Especially after we talked about this. Good pointers!